# Pyinstaller says I made a virus

Tags: python, pyinstaller, virus

I made a game in pygame called *Balls to the Walls* and I encounter an error when building the program in pyinstaller. I run:
`C:\Users\Ben pyinstaller --windowed --icon=logo.ico  BallsWalls.py`
The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 205, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 189, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1033, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 973, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Student\Balls to the Walls\BallsWalls.spec", line 18, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
          ^^^^
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 625, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 738, in assemble
    self._retry_operation(icon.CopyIcons, build_name, self.icon)
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 992, in _retry_operation
    return func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 209, in CopyIcons
    return CopyIcons_FromIco(dstpath, [srcpath])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 143, in CopyIcons_FromIco
    hdst = win32api.BeginUpdateResource(dstpath, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 208, in BeginUpdateResource
    with _pywin32error():
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "B:\Python Installs\Python 3.11.6\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (225, 'BeginUpdateResourceW', 'Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.')
```

Any way to fix this at all?
I tried other questions and they don't work, so don't flag this as duplicate. This question does not ask multiple questions. It only asks one.

Comment: It's unanswerable: the heuristics used by AV engines (and it's not pyinstaller making this decision, it's an installed AV engine) are deliberately obscured (and constantly changing) so people who _really are_ making viruses can't evade them. There's no reason to believe that even if we could give you an answer that worked today that it would keep working tomorrow.

Comment: Can I delete an AV engine?

Comment: If you're an administrator, generally, yes; better, you should be able to _temporarily disable_ one. If this is a corporate machine, talk to your IT team; if it's personal, this may be as simple as pausing Windows Defender.

Comment: I'll try now, thanks!

Comment: (I've also seen corporate systems where they had a specific folder name that developers were expected to use for their work, with enforcement relaxed in anything under that folder... but that's in the category of "talk to your IT team"... that said, it looks like Windows Defender too supports that category of folder exclusions)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're developing in a folder that your antivirus has been told to ignore.

[Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26) suggests the following steps on Windows 11:

1. Open Start -> Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Virus & threat protection
2. Select "manage settings", go to "exclusions", and click "add or remove exclusions".
3. Select "Add an exclusion", then select a directory that contains the development work where you don't want Windows Defender interfering with pyinstaller.

---

You can also temporarily disable the antivirus as a whole.